# How to make the backslash used to escape characters in a string not count

Tags: python, replace, escaping

I have a phrase like this:

```
"My name is Manuel, the &quot;most handsome&quot;"
```

I escape it because I want to put it in a json and it would look like this:

```
sentence=sentence.replace("&quot;","\"")
"My name is Manuel, the \"most handsome\""
```

And now I have to take the position of what is in quotes, that is: most handsome
But to give me the position with a finditer it counts the backslash \ and I don't want it to count it, is there a way I can't count the backslash

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&quot;` with just `"`: `sentence = sentence.replace("&quot;",'"')`. To get JSON representation, use `json.dumps()` from `json` module.

```
>>> import json
>>> sentence = "My name is Manuel, the &quot;most handsome&quot;"
>>> sentence = sentence.replace("&quot;",'"')
>>> print(sentence)
My name is Manuel, the "most handsome"
>>> sentence.find('"')
23
>>> sentence[23:]
'"most handsome"'
>>> print(json.dumps(sentence))
"My name is Manuel, the \"most handsome\""
```